# Entra ID custom claims in ID-Token, UserInfo

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-entra-id

With Entra ID "Custom claims provider" it seems to be possible to add claims to the Access Token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/custom-extension-get-started

Is it also possible to add claims to ID token and UserInfo endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, it's possible to add custom claims to **ID token** using Entra ID "Custom claims provider". But for `/userinfo` endpoint, it's not possible as it returns only [**specific**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/userinfo#userinfo-response) claims.

In my case, I followed same document and created one Function app with HTTP Trigger function by editing code and got its function URL:

[image]

Now, I configured one custom authentication extension named **Token issuance event** and added function URL here:

[image]

In Azure AD, I registered one application by enabling **implicit flow** options and changed below properties in **`Manifest`** tab:

[image]

Now, I assigned **custom claims provider** to the application by adding claims like this:

[image]

In the Function App, I added **Microsoft** as identity provider in `Authentication` tab:

[image]

To test the application, I ran below authorization request in browser and got **`ID token`** with **custom claims** successfully like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={AppID}&response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&scope=openid&state=12345&nonce=12345
```

[image]